# Passing Data From Controller to View MVC-5

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-5

I'm currently stuyding MVC-5 ASP.NET and following this tutorial: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Fu9v2MIDlTA

I have successfully created my view and controller and therefore my HeLLO WORLD display. Now I'm currently in part 2 of the tutorial wherein I'm passing my data from controller to View.

Here are the codes:

Home Controller:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;
using System.Web.Mvc;

namespace WebApplication2.Controllers
{
    public class HomeController : Controller
    {
        //
        // GET: /Home/
        public ActionResult Index()
        {
            return View();
        }

        public ActionResult ShowHome()
        {
            ViewData["CurrentTime"] = DateTime.Now.ToString();
            return View("Home");
        }
    }
}
```

View:

```
@{
    ViewBag.Title = "Home";
}
<html>

<head>
    <title>
        WELCOME TO MVC 5
    </title>
    <body>
        <div>
            This is my homepage! <br/>
            TIME: <%= ViewData["CurrentTime"]%>
        </div>
    </body>
</head>

</html>
```

The question is: Why is it that when I type the part:
<% %>, my ide is not reading it? I mean, the speaker in the tutorial is using I think Visual Studio 2013 Ultimate. When he types <% >%, there is intellisense.

I'm using Visual Studio 2013 Express for WEB, when I type

```
ViewData["CurrentTime"] = DateTime.Now.ToString();
```

The IDE doesn't recognize it and it prints this as a string. :(

Comment: Since you're using the **Razor** view-engine, you're gonna need this instead: `@ViewData["CurrentTime"]`.

Comment: It's the **OLD** ASP.NET syntax. With new syntax `<%= ViewData["CurrentTime"]%>` has to be changed to `@ViewData["CurrentTime"]`. BTW I'd drop that tutorial in favor of something newer. Concepts didn't change much but everything else changed a lot...

Comment: @haim770 right, I supposed to write "ASP.NET syntax" instead of  instead of "Razor", thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Glenn you got confused between they way on how code blocks where annotated in aspx pages and how they are used in the Razor view engine nowadays.

You can see Razor in action right at the top of your View:

```
@{
    ViewBag.Title = "Home";
}
```

And thats how you do it. The curly braces are optional, if you use a single expression, so in your case you could just write

```
<div>
    This is my homepage! <br/>
    TIME: @ViewData["CurrentTime"]
</div>
```

Scott Gu has written a pretty good article about the differences between the two systems: http://weblogs.asp.net/scottgu/introducing-razor

As a rule of thumb: If its an .aspx file, use `<% %>`. If it is a .cshtml or .vbhtml use `@{ }`